# Google analytics custom dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, analytics

i'm currently trying to add a custom dimension to google analytics.
The goal is to be able to have reports on what user did with their client_id.
So i've added a "client_id" custom dimension in Admin->property
Name: client_id
scope: hit
Active : true

Then in my code just after the head i add :

```
 gtag('config', 'UA-133344089-1', {
        'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'client_id'}
    });

    // Sends an event that passes 'client_id' as a parameter.
    gtag('event', 'client_id', {'client_id': 12});
```

But after that in a custom report where i add Metric group : pageviews
And Dimension Drilldowns : client_id
type:explorer

I can then see the data from yesterday, but can't check the data of today and be sure i've send the client_id correctly.

Is there any way to check that in real time, so i don't have to wait for tomorrow to check if i get the client_id in Google Analytics ?
Also is this the good way to implement custom dimension to be able to see activities of each client (for exemple having a reporter with :
Client_id:12, pageviews:20) ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to check that in real time, so i don't have to wait for tomorrow to check if i get the client_id in Google Analytics ?

The real-time api does not include custom dimensions and metrics.

> I can then see the data from yesterday, but can't check the data of today and be sure i've send the client_id correctly.

The standard reports take between 24 - 48 hours before they complete processing you will need to wait until then before you can check it.

> Also is this the good way to implement custom dimension to be able to see activities of each client (for exemple having a reporter with : Client_id:12, pageviews:20) ?

This should work fine just remember that you will need to send it on all requests.